# Get Windows registry into Mathematica as an association

Tags: associations, windows

Windows probably is the only operating system that has a separate database of configuration instructions and paths. The windows registry looks exactly like a giant nested association. Also probably is the fastest and most efficient key-value store there is which is read and written to in real-time. Is there a way to import the Windows registry into a Mathematica association?

The keys of the registry are basic string which Mathematica support and values can be any of the following:

- Binary data
- Unsigned integers
- Symbolic links
- Multi-string values
- Resource list / Resource descriptor (Plug and play hardware)
- 64 bit-integers

Mathematica has a very powerful query language which can then be used to analyse it.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Do you have an example of a block of registry entries that someone could use instead of having to find one themselves?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Well I tried to use the built in registry editor to export it as a json but there is no such option.

Comment: Check ``?Developer`*Registry*``, for example ``Developer`EnumerateRegistrySubkeys["HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"]``.

Comment: Also note that there are *hidden* keys in the Windows registry. You can access them only having appropriate permissions.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you it works but is there a way to get the entire hive structure so I can perform queries like keys with values matching a certain criterion. This functionality only accesses the registry one level at a time.

Comment: @user13892 Unfortunately I have very little experience with this *undocumented* functionality. But it worked reliably and sufficiently fast when I used it. I hope that someone more knowledgeable will answer this.

Comment: Have you tried "regedit.exe" and export as "*.txt'?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that it would be nice if we could import the registry as a nested association. This is really not an answer to that, but I thought it might still be useful to others.

I discovered this post in a search. I was looking for a way to read the value of a registry key from Mathematica. (I needed the path to a data directory of a particular installed software tool.) After a bit of hunting, I came upon the fact that Microsoft .NET includes a class named Registry which provides static methods for manipulating the registry. I found the assembly containing that class on my computer.

The code below uses Mathematica's NET/Link to interface with that class and read the value of a registry key. (I used a common key for this post, so others can run the code.)

Information on NET/Link can be found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/Overview.html).

Information on the Registry class can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=netframework-4.8).

And here is the code: (There are a few continuation \ to remove. )

```
(* Install NETLink *)

Needs["NETLink`"]

InstallNET[];


(* Load the assembly that contains the Registry class *)
(* I found the location by searching for it on my computer *)

asmName = 
  "C:\\Program \
Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.NETCore.App\\2.1.11\\Microsoft.Win32.\
Registry.dll";

asm = LoadNETAssembly[asmName];


(* Since this we will use static methods we will not insantiate a \
Registry object, so we need to load the type explicitly *)

registryType = LoadNETType["Microsoft.Win32.Registry"];

(* we can use NETTypeInfo to see the fields and methods *)
(* I deleted the output before posting because its lengthy *)

NETTypeInfo@registryType

(* output deleted *)


(* one of the functions is GetValue *)
(* here we use it to get the value of a key *)

key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows \
NT\\CurrentVersion";

valueName = "SystemRoot";

systemRootPath = Registry`GetValue[key, valueName, -1]

(* "C:\\windows" *)
```

Comment: `"SystemRoot" /. 
Developer\`ReadRegistryKeyValues[
  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows \
NT\\CurrentVersion"]` also gives `"C:\\WINDOWS"`